# Requesting simple step by step set up for "Wacom Cintiq 16"

Tags: drivers, usb, tablet, wacom

I recently purchased a "Wacom Cintiq 16" (not the pro). Here is a link to it, just for clarity.

[https://www.amazon.com/Wacom-Cintiq-Drawing-Tablet-DTK1660K0A/dp/B07L77GTTY](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B07L77GTTY)

I would like to run this on an Ubuntu 18.04 operating system. (My machine is a Dell Inspiron 15 3000 series, if that information helps).

When I connect the hdmi and usb to my laptop, the wacom monitor works and so does the pen. **However, the pen acts like a mouse instead of a pen?**

I looked at the settings, and my computer sees the new wacom cintiq as a new monitor. **However**, it is not detecting the stylus/tablet.

I am able to use the device, but it doesn't do pressure sensitivity, tilt, etc., that are specifics to pen.

Any help is appreciated, especially if you have this particular product and are able to use them on your ubuntu machine.

Comment: We are trying to evaluate this tablet's suitability for our Ubuntu users as well and are similarly stuck. With Ubuntu 18.04, the tablet is detected; by setting **Screen Display** to `Mirror`, and then **Wacom Tablet » Test Your Settings** it is possible to draw with the stylus on the test input panel, but neither the **Stylus** nor **Tablet** settings seem to recognise the devices fully. We need to be able to annotate PDF files: opening them in LibreOffice Draw works although clunky, but just about OK. Evince does not seem to allow PDF annotation, is there a supported PDF reader that does?

Comment: I have now upgraded my test machine from Ubuntu 18.04 to Ubuntu 20.04, and the driver support for the tablet is improved, with both **Stylus** and **Tablet** settings now available in the **Wacom Tablet** settings.

Comment: Following the instructions from https://linuxwacom.github.io/ I was able to make the Wacom Cintiq 16 work in Ubuntu 16.04 including pressure sensitivity.